# How can we find statistics on computer specs so we know what to target with our web apps?

Tags: javascript, performance, flash

What I really want to know is the distribution of CPU speed, # of cores, available memory, video card specs, and display resolution among English-speaking web users, but other stats would be helpful as well.

I'd like to know this information so I can make some informed decisions about what I can get away with and who I will be cutting out regarding the performance of my web game, prior to its release.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics (among several others) can tell you display resolution, color depth, and guesses about bandwidth.  It will also tell you Flash version and browser version.

You won't find reliable data for the others, because even if you did survey a selection of the population, it will vary from site to site.  The only way to get that data would be with a browser plugin, which your users would find intrusive.

You can make educated guesses about some of this based on OS and other metrics.  If they're running windows 7 and have a 1920x1080 screen resolution, it is safe to assume they're not running a 33MHz 486.  Don't read into it too much though.

Comment: Site analytics are useless for PLANNING a site, because you don't have a site or visits yet to collect data from

Comment: @AdamHarte, I had assumed he had similar sites under his belt, but I suppose that isn't a good assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is good. But you can also use StatCounter which reports faster than Google Analytics. And yes, it's easy to use ( for a beginner ). Here: http://statcounter.com/

There are different sections for different analytics like the OS your site viewers are using, the Network Connection details, Screen Resolution and much more. There are many more features available.